# Java TimeZones: how to get UTC time values based on Console settings?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc

For example, when I extract from a database a Date() variable, it contains a date with "+04:00" shift.
According to my locale's settings.
So, UTC time is "ourTime" MINUS 4 hours.

Then, a user tells where he/she is from. Now, we need to save his/her shift. 
LET'S SAY it is -01:00.
And finally, this user tells us where's he/she is heading, let's say this place has a time shift of +05:00.

How do we save this town's or place's time shifts in the DB so that according to where he/she's from
we could calculate the time difference with our current locale?
Also, date save light things, how do we work with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

As long as you're using `java.util.Date` objects (or `java.sql.Date`, or `java.sql.Timestamp`) the database will contain UTC time, that's what `java.util.Date` holds internally.

You need to format and/or parse these dates according to local timezone. Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information. Of course, if you have dates in the database that you manually parsed, then you may be SOL.